# How to creat a category with DISQUS

Tags: api, categories, disqus

I'm having trouble to make this works:

[API console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zevX.png)

**code error :**

```
{
  "code":22,
  "response":"You do not have admin privileges on forum 'fabien-greard'"
}
```

I tried to change my app permission to : 
Read, Write, Manage Forums (without any effect).

My app is using the same username than my forum (i'm the owner)

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you figure out how to do this?

Comment: As far as I remember I endup switching to something else.

Comment: Well, i could do this.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is by handling **API** request in Postman.

For it, we need the credentials from our site's **Disqus** api:
[image]

With this in mind, we go to postman and we use that credentials for sending request:
[image]

Two parameters more are required here: *forum*, the site where you want to create the categories, and the category's name as *title*.

Don't forget to use an admin user to have permissions for managing forums, the api will know you are admin by using also the access token.